# Spring MVC 3 and validation error

Tags: java, spring, validation, spring-mvc, hibernate-validator

I'm trying to create simple validation with javax based on Spring MVC. I have enable annotation-driven. I want to display errors int the form but I get 500 page error:

**500 error page**

```
org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.validation.BindException: org.springframework.validation.BeanPropertyBindingResult: 2 errors
Field error in object 'profile' on field 'email': rejected value [xx@ss]; codes [Pattern.profile.email,Pattern.email,Pattern.java.lang.String,Pattern]; arguments [org.springframework.context.support.DefaultMessageSourceResolvable: codes [profile.email,email]; arguments []; default message [email],[Ljavax.validation.constraints.Pattern$Flag;@718df055,^[_A-Za-z0-9-]+(\.[_A-Za-z0-9-]+)*@[A-Za-z0-9]+(\.[A-Za-z0-9]+)*(\.[A-Za-z]{2,})$]; default message [Nieprawidłowy e-mail]
Field error in object 'profile' on field 'login': rejected value [xx]; codes [Size.profile.login,Size.login,Size.java.lang.String,Size]; arguments [org.springframework.context.support.DefaultMessageSourceResolvable: codes [profile.login,login]; arguments []; default message [login],20,4]; default message [Login musi min. długość 4 znaków, max. 20 znaków]
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:894)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:789)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:641)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
```

**Controller**

```
@RequestMapping(value="/register", method=RequestMethod.POST)
    public String register(
            @Valid Profile profile,
            @RequestParam("recaptcha_challenge_field") String challenge,
            @RequestParam("recaptcha_response_field") String response, 
            BindingResult result, Model model, HttpServletRequest request) {

        ReCaptchaResponse cResponse = captcha.checkAnswer(request.getRemoteAddr(), challenge, response);
        if(result.hasErrors() || !cResponse.isValid()) {
            String message = cResponse.getErrorMessage();
            String html = captcha.createRecaptchaHtml(message, null);
            model.addAttribute("profile", profile);
            model.addAttribute(CAPTCHA_HTML, html);
            return "login/register";
        }
        return "ok";
    }
```

**Part of model (only this fields are validate)**

```
@NotBlank
    @Size(min=4, max=20)
    @Pattern(regexp="^([\\w]+)$")
    private String login;

    @NotBlank
    @Pattern(regexp=("^[_A-Za-z0-9-]+(\\.[_A-Za-z0-9-]+)*@[A-Za-z0-9]+(\\.[A-Za-z0-9]+)*(\\.[A-Za-z]{2,})$"))
    private String email;
```

How to resolve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe try to do maven clean and install into your local repo?